# Create EnumMap from List of values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension, enum-map

I would like to define an extension of the `enum class` which accepts a list of values in the same order as the enum constants and outputs an `EnumMap`.

What I've been able to do instead is create and extension of the `List<V>` object with an array of the keys from `Enum<K>.values()` as input.

It seems the difficulty is `enum class` is not itself a object having a `.values()` method. So perhaps my request is not sensible.

Here is a working example using the list extension method.

```
import java.util.*

enum class Shoes(
    val title: String,
    val weight: Double) {
    WORKBOOT("tough", 11.0),
    SNEAKER("fast", 6.0),
    SLIPPER("soft", 3.0);
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val prices= listOf(11.5,8.2,3.5)
    val map = prices.enumMapOf(Shoes.values())
    map.print()
}

inline fun <reified K : Enum<K>, V> List<V>.enumMapOf(keys:Array<K>): EnumMap<K, V> {
    val map = EnumMap<K, V>(K::class.java)
    keys.forEachIndexed{i,k-> map[k]=this[i]}
    return map
}

fun <K:Enum<K>,V> EnumMap<K,V>.print() {
    this.forEach{k,v-> println("%d: %s --> %.2f".format(k.ordinal,k.name,v)) }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the main thing you're missing is the [`enumValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-values.html) method that can give you the values of a generic enum.

This would allow you to do this (I've rearranged the code of creating the `EnumMap` as well, you can stick to your own solution if this seems too complicated of course):

```
inline fun <reified K : Enum<K>, V> Enum<K>.mappedTo(values: List<V>): EnumMap<K, V> {
    return enumValues<K>().zip(values).toMap(EnumMap(K::class.java))
}
```

Of course this issue now is the call syntax - this function would have to be called like this, *on an instance of an enum*:

```
Shoes.WORKBOOT.mappedTo(listOf(11.5, 8.2, 3.5))
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense. It would be nicer to make this call:

```
Shoes.mappedTo(listOf(11.5, 8.2, 3.5))
```

But as far as I know, there is no way to achieve this syntax, because you can't add an extension to the companion object of the generic enum and then expect to call that on a specific enum's companion object - those don't inherit from each other like that.

So perhaps instead of creating an extension, you could use a regular function, and get the enum's type from the generic parameter instead of the receiver:

```
inline fun <reified K : Enum<K>, V> mapEnumTo(values: List<V>): EnumMap<K, V> {
    return enumValues<K>().zip(values).toMap(EnumMap(K::class.java))
}

mapEnumTo<Shoes, Double>(listOf(11.5, 8.2, 3.5))
```

You do have to specify the type of the key here as well, because you can't have a generic type parameter that's explicit and then another that's implicit. But I think this is pretty nice syntax, as you see the key and value types of the map you're creating.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround to eliminate explicit `Double` from @zsmb13's answer, you can borrow a standard Scala trick of splitting into two method calls with separate type argument lists, one of which is explicit and the other inferred:

```
interface EnumMapper<K : Enum<K>> {
    operator fun <V> invoke(values: List<V>): EnumMap<K, V>
}

inline fun <reified K : Enum<K>> mapEnumTo() = object : EnumMapper<K> {
    override operator fun <V> invoke(values: List<V>): EnumMap<K, V> {
        return enumValues<K>().zip(values).toMap(EnumMap(K::class.java))
    }
}

mapEnumTo<Shoes>()(listOf(11.5, 8.2, 3.5))
```

Answer (score -1):

In the enum itself:
private val shoeMap by lazy { values().associateBy { it.title } }